# Archive binary has reversed hex signature

Tags: linux, bash, sh, hexdump

## Context

I'm playing Bandit on OverTheWire, and [level thirteen](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit13.html) requires unzipping various compressed file formats without knowing the file extension. To do this, I have been comparing the hexdump with file signatures from [Gary Kessler's website](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html).

What I've noticed however is that the hex signature appears backwards. For example, take this `gz, tgz gzip` archive file:

```
0000000 8b1f 0808 5006 5eb4 0302 6164 6174 2e32
0000010 6962 006e 3d01 c202 42fd 685a 3139 5941
0000020 5326 8e59 1c4f 00c8 1e00 ff7f f9fb da7f
...
```

With the signature `8b1f 0808` is backwards, as compared to what Gary Kessler's website indicates:

```
1F 8B 08        .‹. GZ, TGZ         GZIP archive file
                        VLT         VLC Player Skin file
```

## Question

Why is the signature backwards? `1F 8B 08` vs `8b1f 0808`. The first file encountered is a hexdump of an archive file, `data.txt`, and has a proper signature of `1f8b 0808` (found using `head data.txt`), which aligns perfectly with the signature. However, when I run `xxd -r data.txt | hexdump` I once again `8b1f 0808`.

I am aware of Big endian vs Little endian encoding, but I don't think that is what is causing this. It seems reversed like big / little endian but in the wrong way.

Comment: They seem to be just pairwise "backwards", so it looks to me like a [little endian vs. big endian](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/big-endian-and-little-endian) effect. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Try `xxd -g1`, so it prints byte-by-byte.

Comment: @user1934428 Could you please elaborate? If it's big endian I don't know why it would appear like this. For example, `0001 11111` would be `1f` in big endian form, but `8f` in little endian. Is it being written as `1111 1000`?

Comment: 0001 in the reversed endianness would be 0100 of course, not 1000. You have to reverse the bytes, not the nybbles. Of course this assumes that we have 16-bit-words. With 32-bits, you have to consider 4-byte-groups. The example posted looks like 16-bit. Aside from this, such a question should be posted at i.e. [su], because it is not related to programming.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Oh thank you! I checkedout what the man page had to say about the -g flag, but I know that what I don't understand what 'grouping' is. If there's anything else you could share about it I would be very appreciative.

Comment: What CPU type and OS/distro are you running this under? I suspect this is due to the endianness of your architecture, but I'm not sure of the details. Try `printf '\001\002\003\004\005\006\007\010' | xxd -g4` and `... -g8` to see how it orders the bytes in 4- and 8-byte groupings.